# How I change the text color of bullets in ioslides rmarkdown with a css file

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

I am trying to change the color of the text in bullets in ioslides rmarkdown using a css file.  I tried using p but there I couldn't.

```
p { 
display: block;
font-size: 30px;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
font-weight: bold;
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are so very close.  You need to change the `ul` properties (unordered list).

```
ul {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

Note that this will change the color of the bullet and the font.  I've searched for a way to color the bullet separately, but it appears the default behavior is to color the bullet the same as the font.  To override this doesn't seem straight-forward.